# Setting value inside a rich:editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, richfaces

I want to enter the value of a checkbox in a rich:editor using javascript. A h:InputTextArea** works fine with the same code but when I change to a rich:Editor, the values are not entered.
Is there something am missing about the editor ? Am using richfaces 3.3.3 final

My javascript :
'recieved' is a parameter for the function and all the logs show the correct values

```
var newValue =(document.getElementById 
("viewsInclude:scheduleView:scheduleEmail").value) + ("[" + received + "]");
                    console.log("the value " + newValue);
                    document.getElementById("viewsInclude:scheduleView:scheduleEmail").value = newValue;
                    console.log("The new VALUE: " + document.getElementById("viewsInclude:scheduleView:scheduleEmail").value);
document.getElementById
("viewsInclude:scheduleView:scheduleEmail").value=newValue;
```

The jsp code

```
  <h:panelGrid>
                                       <rich:dataGrid var="column" columns="4" border="0" value="#{newScheduleBean.headers}" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                                         <h:outputLabel value="#{column.header}"/>
                                         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mobileColCheckbox1" onclick="scheduleManipulateInputEmail('#{column.header}',event)">
                                             <a4j:support   event="onchange" action="#{newScheduleBean.fetchValue(column.header)}">
                                             </a4j:support>
                                         </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                     </rich:dataGrid>
                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                    <rich:spacer height="8px"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>

                                <h:panelGrid columns="2"  style="font-size:14px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Compose Email To Send:"/>
                                    <h:panelGrid id="emailEditor">
                                        <rich:editor  id="scheduleEmail" value="#{newScheduleBean.editorStr}" theme="advanced"  width="500" height="300"  >
                                            <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top"/>                               
                                            <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="center"/>
                                        </rich:editor>
                                    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code? I don't understand what the checkbox has to do with the editor. However when you want to use JS to do some thing with the editor you'll have to use an API, it's not a simple textarea like `h:inputTextArea`

Comment: Thanks Makhiel your response. The checkbox is inside a datagrid which is populated by a sql query whereby there are as many check-boxes as the result-set.When user ticks the checkbox,its value is updated inside the editor, inside square brackets have updated the code sample. Kindly expound on the API usage in this context

Comment: You can access the JS component with `#{rich:component('id')}`, RF 3 uses TinyMCE for the editor but I'm not familiar with it, check their [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/)

Comment: Thanks Makhiel. I finally decided to use another page in between such that i save the selected value in a bean property and use the property as the value of the editor .The #{rich:component('id')} was giving me an error in javascript